# Does an "update-update" conflict get created from the same node in P2P replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

I have been told that an update-update conflict is being created in a production environment, which is set up using p2p replication, because of concurrent update by stored procedures.

The [msdn reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934199(v=sql.110).aspx) states the update-update conflict happens only when a same row is being updated by different nodes.